# Odd cgi behaviour

Tags: perl, apache, logging, cgi

I am getting some very annoying behaviour from my perl cgi scripts running under apache.
I get referer information added on the end of simple print statements, and it's driving me nuts.

```
[Sun Feb 20 21:34:47 2011] [error] [client xx] ruid: 48, referer: http://www.x.com/
[Sun Feb 20 21:34:47 2011] [error] [client xx] euid: 48, referer: http://www.x.com/
[Sun Feb 20 21:34:47 2011] [error] [client xx] test, referer: http://www.x.com/
[Sun Feb 20 21:34:47 2011] [error] [client xx] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi, referer: http://www.x.com/
```

This only seems to happen when the url is reached by navigating from another page (hence having a referer yes).  The above apache log output was produced with the below incredibly simple depo script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

print STDERR "ruid: $<\n";
print STDERR "euid: $>\n";
print STDERR "test\n";
```

Anyone seen this before?  It feels like an apache setting i need to turn off.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your apache config files (`httpd.conf` and friends) and find the `CustomLog` directive which is used by your error log to see which `LogFormat` it uses, then modify that `LogFormat` (or create a new one) to remove `%{Referer}` from the list of fields to include in the log messages.  (And don't forget to reload the apache config after changing it, of course.)

Comment: It seems only my access_log is using a CustomLog directive.

Comment: I Tried adding `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" test` `CustomLog logs/error_log test` to my httpd.conf, but now i just get an extra line in my error log that looks like an access log entry. The original strange error log entries are unchanged I am seeing in the documentation that it's not possible to change the error_log format, though i dont remember ever having this referer info on other servers...

Comment: @Matt: I stand corrected; I've just double-checked the docs and found the same: "It is not possible to customize the error log by adding or removing information." You could probably hook into the logging phase with an apache module to inhibit referer logging, but, otherwise, it doesn't look like this can be done.

Comment: Seems that way.  Thanks anyway.